# Relation dbo.MyTable not found while schema and table do exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, mono, npgsql

In our MVC 5.2 application on Mono 3.10 I am trying to set up a connection with a PostgreSQL database via Entity Framework 6.1.1. To do this I took the following steps:

1. Included the packages `Npsql` and `Npsql.EntityFramework` via NuGet.
2. Added the section `<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />` to the `configSections` element in `Web.Config`.
3. Added `<remove invariant="Npgsql"></remove>` and `<add name="Npgsql" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.2.2, Culture=neutral" />` to the `DbProviderFactories` element of `system.data` in the `Web.config`.
4. Added the following connection string `<add name="ZkTestDatabaseConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=ZkTestDatabase;User Id=test;Password=password;CommandTimeout=20;" providerName="Npgsql" />` that connects with Entity Framework context.
5. Created a schema named `dbo`, a database named `ZkTestDatabase`, a user named `test`, and a table named `dbo.Crops` to this database in PostgreSQL (see [this script](https://gist.github.com/erooijak/e70012c35a29ca729bb0)).

When I am logged in with the user `test` and do `select * from dbo.Crops;` (I also tried making a table via `create table "dbo.Crops";` instead of `create table dbo.Crops;`. I get the proper output.

Now, when I go a page with a model `Crop` (as per conventions this maps to a table `Crops`) I get the message:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException
ERROR: 42P01: relation "dbo.Crops" does not exist

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): Npgsql.
Exception stack trace:
at Npgsql.NpgsqlState+<ProcessBackendResponses>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in 
<filename unknown>:0 at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject 
(Boolean cleanup) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I am very happy that the application understands that it needs to connect to a database and find a relation `dbo.Crops`. I am a bit sad however that the relation cannot be found.

*Edit: while performing `select * from pg_tables;` the following is returned:

```
     schemaname     |        tablename        | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers   
--------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------
 public             | dbo.Crops               | zktest     |            | t          | f        | f
```

I have no idea why this error pops up and I have exhausted all capabilities within my limited understanding. I hope someone else sees a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a select * from pg_tables and see what comes back. That should get you on the right course.

Comment: Joshua D Drake thank you. We do this this and let you know the result!

Comment: Okay I've added the result to the answer, seems that the `Table name` is `dbo.Crops`, but the table does not belong to a schema.

Comment: Thanks! The table can now be found. I did it by adding the table to the schema `dbo` and renaming it to `Crops` (uppercase start). How to do this in one statement I do not know, but that does not matter. The error now is: `ERROR: 42703: column Extent1.Id does not exist`. :-). Why is it called Extent1.Id. It is just a Crop ID?!

Comment: Still no luck! Do you know how to rename tables to `Extent1.Id` instead of the `Id`?

Comment: Added a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948688/column-extent1-id-does-not-exist-in-mono-with-entity-framework-6) here. Thanks a lot Joshua!