# Column Extent1.Id does not exist in Mono with Entity Framework 6 and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, mono, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to map to a PostgreSQL database with Entity Framework using the packages [`Npsql`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) and [`Npsql.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFramework/). I have a database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Crops (
  Id            INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
  Name          TEXT                NOT NULL,
  SowingMonths  INT
);
```

The `Crop` model looks as follows:

```
public class Crop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Month SowingMonths { get; set;} //Month is an enum
}
```

In the database context I map the schema to public since all tables are in the schema public by default in PostgreSQL.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
}
```

Now when I open the view that tries to access Crops of the DbContext I get this message:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException
> ERROR: 42703: column Extent1.Id does not exist
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): Npgsql.
> Exception stack trace:
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlState+d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject (Boolean cleanup) [0x00000] in :0

The good news is the database can find the table now (it could [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941722/relation-dbo-mytable-not-found-while-schema-and-table-do-exist) at first, but it can with the mapping to the public schema in the `OnModelCreating` method). However, it cannot find the column name `Extend.Id`.

Why it tries to look for `Extend.Id` is beyond me. We have defined the property on the `Crops` model as `Id`, why then does it look for `Extend.Id`? But considering this is the case, how can I get this to work? Can I just create a database table with a property `Extend1.Id` instead of `Id`? And if so, how do I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm convinced that there is a typographical error somewhere in your code. The table "Id" simply does not exist. Capital letters maybe?

Comment: Thank you you master hero. This was indeed the case. After altering the column names to upper case the problem was solved! Thank you thank you thank you. PS Could you please tell me what `[Extent1]` is?